# Problem of finding an optimal weak homomorphism between two graphs

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, optimization, category-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $V(\cdot), E(\cdot)$ denote the vertex and edge sets, respectively, of a given graph. Given two graphs $G$ and $H$, a [(weak) homomorphism (definition 1.14)](https://scholarscompass.vcu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2951&context=etd) is a mapping $f:V(G) \to V(H)$ such that $(u,v) \in E(G) \implies (f(u),f(v))\in E(H) \lor f(u) = f(v)$.[1]

I am interested in the problem of find a weak homomorphism $f: V(G) \to V(H)$ that maximizes the cardinality of the image $|\{f(u) ; u \in V(G) \}|$. Alternatively, find a weak homomorphism $f: V(G) \to V(H)$ that maximizes the cardinality $|\{(s, t) \in E(H) ; \exists (u, v) \in E(G) \text{ such that } (s, t) = (f(u), f(v))\}|$.

Is there a name for such a problem?

Intuitively, I am interested the problem of glueing vertices of $G$ together to represent as much of $H$ as possible.

---

I found this for a start: [maximum graph homomorphisms](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecswamy/papers/homomorphfnl.pdf)!

Comment: Your operation of glueing adjacent vertices is called edge contraction. You can say you search a homomorphism but allowing edge contraction in $G$. I found a duplicate of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/quoestions/2076034/graph-homomorphisms-allowing-contractions-of-edges

Comment: @caduk hmmm, im not only contracting edges though. im allowing vertices to join even if there does not exist an edge connecting them. brw there is a typo in ur link in "quoestions"